# Given $A + B + C = \pi $, find $ \frac{\cos A}{\sin B\sin C} + \frac{\cos B}{\sin C\sin A} + \frac{\cos C}{\sin A\sin B} $

Tags: trigonometry

> Given 
>   $$ A + B + C = \pi $$ 
>   Find
>   $$ \frac{\cos A}{\sin B\sin C} + \frac{\cos B}{\sin C\sin A} + \frac{\cos C}{\sin A\sin B} $$

Comment: You have tried what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Use the formulas
$$\cos(\alpha)=\frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc}$$ and so on and
$$\frac{\sin(\alpha)}{\sin(\beta)}=\frac{a}{b}$$ and so on.
Doing so you will get
$$\frac{4R^2(a+b+c)(-a+b+c)(a-b+c)(a+b-c)}{2a^2b^2c^2}$$
the use $$A=\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}$$ and $$A=\frac{abc}{4R}$$
where $R$ is the circumradius and $$s=\frac{a+b+c}{2}$$.
I got $2$ as the searched result!

Comment: Correct answer is 2

Comment: Yes i forgot the two in the denominator, so $$\frac{4}{2}=2$$

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite,

$$A= \frac{\cos A}{\sin B \sin C} + \frac{\cos B}{\sin A \sin C} + \frac{\cos C}{\sin A \sin B} =\frac{\sin 2A + \sin 2B + \sin 2C}{2\sin A \sin B \sin C} 
$$

and reexpress the numerator,
$$\sin 2A + \sin 2B + \sin 2C$$
$$= 2\sin(A+B)\cos(A-B) + 2\sin C \cos C$$

$$= 2\sin C \cos(A-B) - 2\sin C \cos (A+B)$$
$$=2\sin C \left[\cos(A-B)-\cos (A+B)\right]$$
$$=4\sin A \sin B \sin C$$

which cancels the denominator. Thus,

$$A = 2$$

Comment: How to reexpress the denominator  ? Which formula is applied there?

Comment: @SanaMalik - the trig identity sin x + sin y = 2 sin (x+y)/2 cos (x-y)/2.

Answer (score 0):

Hint. Use:

$$ tan A + tan B + tan C = tan A \cdot tan B \cdot tan C $$

Comment: How to use this formula?

Comment: $ A + B + C = \pi $, so cos(A) = - cos(B + C). Use formula for cos(x + y) and bring sum to $ 3 - \frac{tan A + tan B + tan C}{tan A \cdot tan B \cdot tan C} $